# How can I check if a text file contains a whole word?

Tags: go

I am trying to check if a text file contains a certain word. However it will return true even for some letters in a string. For example:

Entered string: gdo

Computer found: kin**gdo**m

```
var word = strings.ToLower(string(a))

// read the whole file at once
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("words.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
s := string(b)

// Check whether s contains substring text
if strings.Contains(s, word) == true {
    fmt.Println("this is a word ", word)
} else {
    fmt.Println("this isn't a word ", word)
}
```

Comment: `gdo` is not in the string `kinGDOm`, and this code would not match that. If you need to match whole words, why not use a regex?

Comment: That's exactly what `Contains` does. If you want to search for a word, you need to define what "word" means in your context - should "self" match "self-healing"? Should it match "self" at the start or end of the file? Start or end of a line? What about at the end of a sentence, like "self." or "self?" or "self!"? Computers have no internal concept of "words", so when you search for a string within another string, you get exactly what you're seeing. Computers are very literal.

Comment: You might want to use a regex instead and look for the pattern `\bgdo\b` since that takes into consideration word boundaries such as periods and line breaks - https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/

Comment: uhm yes it is....kingdom....kin gdo m @JimB

Comment: @Adrian yes, but how would that be implemented. Easier said than done.

Comment: `"dom"` != `"DOM"`, which is what you have in your original question. As for implementation, why isn't it possible to use a regex?  The regex word boundary might work for enough situations, and if it doesn't, then you need to iterate over all the conditions that _you_ decode, as Adrian explained.

Comment: The "DOM" looks like just a typographical way to highlight that it's matching the text "dom" inside "kingdom" @JimB

Comment: @KevinOlofson it's pretty easy to implement, but as I noted in my first comment, *before you can implement anything you need to define specifically what you mean by "word"*. Computers have no concept of a linguistic word. You have to define what that means in your use case, then you can implement it.

Answer (score 1):

`strings.Contains()` reports if a substrings is contained within a string. It doesn't check for word boundaries, so the behaviour you're seeing is expected.

What you want instead is to recognize every word as a word. There is already the [`strings.Fields()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields) function to split text by whitespace. A simple implementation might look like:

```
func main() {
    source := `
hello
world
kingdom
foo
`
    check := "gdo"
    words := strings.Fields(strings.ToLower(source))

    for _, w := range words {
        if w == check {
            fmt.Println("found", check)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I used `strings.Fields()` because I don't know the contents of your `words.txt` file. You can also use `strings.Split()` if you know the separator is always a single newline or single space.

This will be slow if you're doing a lot of lookups, since it's looping over the `words` array for every lookup. A faster method would be to store it in a map:

```
func main() {
    source := `
hello
world
kingdom
foo
`
    check := "gdo"

    words := make(map[string]struct{})
    for _, w := range strings.Fields(strings.ToLower(source)) {
        words[w] = struct{}{}
    }

    _, ok := words[check]
    if ok {
        fmt.Println("found", check)
    }
}
```

If you're doing just a single lookup the first method will be faster (as this map method will always need to loop the full array at least once to build the map).

I used the somewhat strange looking empty struct for the map value as this doesn't allocate any memory (`words[w] = true` would).

Comment: Note that this won't work for general corpus text because "word" is more complicated and word boundaries may include various whitespace and punctuation characters.

Comment: Considering that the input is `words.txt`, this is probably fine @Adrian. It'll also work for unicode whitespace, although not for `this is "word"`, but that wasn't part of the question/confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. You can convert s into a string array. Then loop through the array to check if it contains the word.

```
var word = strings.ToLower(string(a))

// read the whole file at once
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("words.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
s := string(b)

// convert the string into a string array (words)

content := strings.Split(s, " ")

contains := false

for i:=0 ; i<len(content) ; i++ {
    if content[i] == word {
        contains = true
        break
    }
}

// Check whether s contains substring text
if contains {
    fmt.Println("this is a word ", word)
} else {
    fmt.Println("this isn't a word ", word)
}
```

No need to complicate things. Have a great day :)

Comment: Note that this won't work for general corpus text because "word" is more complicated and word boundaries may include various whitespace and punctuation characters.

Comment: Appreciate your insight but since the question does not mention such specifics, why complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

If case sensitivity isn't priority, you can use the suffixArray from [`index/suffixarray`](https://golang.org/pkg/index/suffixarray/) package.

```
 b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("words.txt")
 if err != nil {
    panic(err)
 }
 
 word := "gdo"
 suffix := suffixarray.New(b) // accepts []byte
 indexList := suffix.Lookup([]byte(word), -1)
 if len(indexList) == 0 {
    fmt.Println("this isn't a word ", word)
    return
 }

 s := string(b)
 // loop through the word indices
 for _, idx := range indexList {
    fmt.Println("this is a word ", string(s[idx:idx+len(word)]))
 }
```